# How to Parse Nested JSON Object in Android studio from Json assets file?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-assets

File Name:  week.json

> I have a problem with Nested Json Objects.I don't know how to implement this with coding as i am new with json objects.  I don't know how to fetch this nested JSon Objects from a json file.

```
    {
    "Saturday": {
        "1": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        },
        "2": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        }
    },
    "Sunday": {
        "1": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        },
        "2": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        }
    },

    "Monday": {
        "1": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        },
        "2": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        }
    },

       "Tuesday": {
        "1": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        },
        "2": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        },

               "3": {
            "english": "Lorem Epsum",
            "Hindi": "Lorem Ipsum in hindi",
            "Urdu": "Lorem ipsum in urdu"
        }
    }
}
```

> How to fetch this nested Json object in Recycler view? did not work with nested json objects. anyone please help???